# Encountering an Access Denied Error While Attempting to Visit the Website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am hosting a static website using Amazon CloudFront and S3. The buckets I have created are example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). For the past 2 weeks the website was working fine. I have also hosted a terms and conditions page and a privacy policy page on the website which was working fine.

Today, I ran an invalidation on the cloudfront cache and since then I am getting access denied error. When I try to access [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), I see the website for a fraction of second and then I see access denied. However, when I try to access the terms and conditions and privacy policy page, it works fine. Basically, I am getting access denied when trying to access the index.html page which is the default root object in my cloudfront distribution.

Anything I may have missed or done wrong when running the invalidation. Please suggest

I have tried creating new origins in the existing cloudfront distribution. That didn't help
I checked the bucket policy, that seems fine. Also I am still able to access other documents in the bucket, so bucket policy is not the issue.
I have disabled the distribution and enabled it. But that didn't help either

Comment: The fact that you see the page, and then it disappears, suggests that you have some dynamic code on the `index.html` page that is attempting to fetch other resources and failing. You could open the **Network** panel in your browser to see what resources it is attempting to fetch.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.